# JS скрипт анимация плавное вращения окружности на определенный угол

Tags: javascript, анимация, canvas

Есть код:

```js
let x = 600; //х центра круга
let y = 300; //у центра круга
let r = 200;
let l = 80;
let a = Math.acos(r / (2 * r) + l / (2 * r));
let rotateAngle = 60 * Math.PI / 180;
let animFlag;
let colours = ["rgba(30, 214, 13, .5)", "rgba(13, 207, 214, .5)", "rgba(240, 233, 101, .5)", "rgba(222, 40, 210, .5)", "rgba(240, 149, 74, .5)", "rgba(156, 144, 134, .5)"];
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function init() {
  let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  if (canvas.getContext) {
    let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.lineWidth = 3.0;
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, .1)";
    ctx.fillRect(600, 0, 600, 600);
    ctx.fillStyle = "green";
    ctx.font = "25px verdana";
    ctx.fillText("Rotate +", 650, 80);
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(13, 207, 214, .5)";
    ctx.fillRect(400, 0, 200, 600);
    ctx.fillStyle = "green";
    ctx.font = "25px verdana";
    ctx.fillText("Rotate -", 450, 80);
    drawWheel();
  }
}

function drawWheel() {
  let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  if (canvas.getContext) {
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      ctx.fillStyle = colours[i];
      //draw 1 out part of circle 
      ctx.strokeStyle = "red"; //color of circl's board 
      ctx.translate(x, y);
      ctx.rotate(rotateAngle);
      ctx.translate(-x, -y);
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(x, y, r, -a, a, false); //arc(centerX, centerY, radius, startingAngle, endingAngle);
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.fill(); //end draw 1 out part of circle 
      //draw 2 inside part of circle 

      ctx.fillStyle = colours[i];
      ctx.strokeStyle = "blue"
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(x + r + l, y, r, Math.PI - a, Math.PI + a);
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.fill(); //end draw 2 inside part of circle 
    }
  }
}

function rotateWheel() {
  let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  if (canvas.getContext) {
    let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.translate(x, y);
    ctx.rotate(rotateAngle);
    ctx.translate(-x, -y);
    drawWheel();
  }
}

function mouseClick(event) {
  let x = event.clientX;
  let y = event.clientY;
  if ((x > 550) && (x < 850) && (y > 0) && (y < 600))
    animFlag = rotateWheel();
}
window.addEventListener("click", mouseClick, false);
```

```html
<body onload="init()">
<canvas id="canvas" width="850" height="800" style="border:1px solid">
    Нужно шагать в ногу со временем!<br />
 Обновите, пожалуйста, браузер.
</canvas>
```

Вопрос: Как получить плавное вращение на 60 градусов по клику? Понимаю что в ctx.rotate надо анимировать rotateAngle?

Comment: что-то не запускается Ваш код. Поправьте

Comment: Исправил...клик мыши сместился совсем за Rotate +

Answer (score 6):

```js
let context = canvas.getContext("2d")
let w, h, cx, cy
let rect = { x: 0,y: 0,s: 0,a: 0 }
let frame_id, start_time, dir
let dest = Math.PI, cur = 0, speed = 1.1

handleResize()

function drawRect() {
  context.fillRect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.s, rect.s)
}

function clear() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, w, h)
}

// взял здесь https://gist.github.com/gre/1650294
function easeInOutQuint(t) {
  return t < .5 ? 16 * t * t * t * t * t : 1 + 16 * (--t) * t * t * t * t
}

function update() {
  clear()

  // время прошедшее со старта анимации
  let t = Date.now() - start_time
  t /= 1000 * speed
  // планировать анимацию пока t меньше 1
  if (t <= 1) frame_id = requestAnimationFrame(update)

  // пропускаем значение через функцию сглаживания
  // ! не обязательно
  t = easeInOutQuint(t)

  // ну и собственно умножая
  // финальный угол на значение
  // возрастающее от 0 до 1
  // мы будем получать плавное движение
  cur = dest * Math.min(t, 1) * dir

  rotate(cur)
}

function rotate(angle) {
  context.save()
  context.translate(cx, cy)
  context.rotate(rect.a + angle)
  context.translate(-cx, -cy)
  drawRect()
  context.restore()
}

function handleResize() {
  w = canvas.width = innerWidth
  h = canvas.height = innerHeight
  cx = w / 2
  cy = h / 2

  rect.s = Math.min(w, h) * 0.6
  rect.x = cx - rect.s / 2
  rect.y = cy - rect.s / 2

  drawRect()
}

function handleClick(e) {
  if (e.x > 0 && e.x < cx) dir = -1
  if (e.x > cx && e.x < w) dir = 1

  // прибавление накопленного угла к текущему углу квадрата
  // чтобы при повторном нажатии
  // анимация начиналась с того же самого места
  rect.a += cur

  // время начала анимации
  start_time = Date.now()

  // отмена предыдущей анимации
  cancelAnimationFrame(frame_id)
  frame_id = requestAnimationFrame(update)

  // обнуление накопленного с предыдущей анимации угла
  cur = 0
}

window.addEventListener("click", handleClick)
window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize)
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

```js
let context = canvas.getContext("2d")
let w, h
let circle = {x: 0, y: 0, r: 0, a: 0}
let frame_id, start_time, dir
let dest = Math.PI, cur = 0, dur = 2

handleResize()

function drawCircle() {
  context.beginPath()
  context.lineWidth = (w+h)/2*0.01
  context.arc(circle.x, circle.y, circle.r, 0, Math.PI * 2)
  context.stroke()

  context.lineWidth = (w+h)/2*0.005
  for (let i = 0; i < Math.PI * 2; i += Math.PI / 10) {
    const x2 = circle.x + circle.r * Math.cos(i)
    const y2 = circle.y + circle.r * Math.sin(i)
    line(circle.x, circle.y, x2, y2)
  }
}

function line(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
  context.beginPath()
  context.moveTo(x1, y1)
  context.lineTo(x2, y2)
  context.stroke()
}

function clear() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, w, h)
}

function easeInOutQuint(t) {
  return t < .5 ? 16 * t * t * t * t * t : 1 + 16 * (--t) * t * t * t * t
}

function update() {
  clear()
  let t = Date.now() - start_time
  t /= 1000 * dur
  if (t <= 1) frame_id = requestAnimationFrame(update)
  t = easeInOutQuint(t)
  cur = dest * Math.min(t, 1) * dir
  rotate(cur)
}

function rotate(angle) {
  context.save()
  context.translate(circle.x, circle.y)
  context.rotate(circle.a + angle)
  context.translate(-circle.x, -circle.y)
  drawCircle()
  context.restore()
}

function handleResize() {
  w = canvas.width = innerWidth
  h = canvas.height = innerHeight

  circle.r = Math.min(w, h) / 2 * 0.6
  circle.x = w / 2
  circle.y = h / 2

  drawCircle()
}

function handleClick(e) {
  if (e.x > 0 && e.x < w / 2) dir = -1
  if (e.x > w / 2 && e.x < w) dir = 1

  circle.a += cur
  start_time = Date.now()
  cancelAnimationFrame(frame_id)
  frame_id = requestAnimationFrame(update)
  cur = 0
}

window.addEventListener("click", handleClick)
window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize)
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: да "черный квадрат Малевича"  вращается, как мой круг также анимировать?

Comment: @Эйссер так там без разницы что вращать. вместо функции `drawRect` можно подставить что угодно

Comment: @Эйссер только нужно будет центр  круга подставить, как ты это делал в своём примере

Comment: @Эйссер вот здесь `context.translate(cx, cy)
  context.rotate(rect.a + angle)
  context.translate(-cx, -cy)`

Comment: а нельзя хоть самый простой код по окружности

Comment: спасиб...все получилось